# How do I upgrade from Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 on Windows?

Tags: ruby

On one machine I seemed to have upgrade to 1.8.7 -- mostly because of the TLS support for sending via Gmail -- but I don't remember how I did it, or what to do and have a laptop on Windows 7.

How do I upgrade for the 1.8.6 from OneClick?

Comment: hmm, I did upgrade from 1.8.7 to 1.9.1 simply by reinstalling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install RubyInstaller RC2, version 1.8.7-p249.

http://rubyinstaller.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use pik, a ruby version manager for windows

- a simple guide: http://www.dixis.com/?p=117